# SMS app received messages multiple times

Tags: android, sms, receiver

I have built an SMS messaging app, which both sends and receives text messages.  In MainActivity, I have a two-dimensional array of people's names and phone numbers, and in my sending class, I have a for loop which sends the same message to all of the recipients by going through each of the numbers:

```
for (i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
    phoneNo = names[i][2] + names[i][3];
    sendMessage(phoneNo, message);
}

private void sendMessage(String phoneNo, String message) {
    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS failed. Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I send a message through the app, I can see very clearly from my own Samsung messaging app that the same message gets sent to each of the numbers in the list, which is perfect.

This is my shortened receiver class:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] smgs = null;
        String infoSender = "";
        String infoSMS = "";

        if (extras != null) {
            // Retrieve the sms message received
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
            smgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < smgs.length; i++) {
                smgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                infoSender += smgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                infoSMS += smgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            }
        }
```

I have found that despite the message being sent out once to each recipient, some recipients (with this app) receive it more than once consecutively.  Hence, I suspected that there was something wrong with my receiver code, which is seemingly treating one received message as several consecutive received messages.  This is not a consistent problem, as different people receive the consecutive messages at different times.

However, what I've also found is that if I hardcode phoneNo in the sending class to just one phone number, or if I have only one phone number in the array in MainActivity, then this problem doesn't occur.  The message still gets sent out once to that one phone number only, but the receiver will always receive it just once as intended.

I am so confused by this now, so can somebody please give some suggestions as to what I could try?  Literally in the last minute, I thought that it could be a problem with createFromPdu being deprecated?  If so, please advise how to change my receiver code, as I couldn't find anything which resembles my current code too much.

Many thanks in advance:-)

Comment: How are you determining that the message is being received multiple times? Are you getting multiple Notifications? Does the message appear more than once in the SMS app? Also, how many times is multiple? Just twice? More than twice? Are you saving the message yourself somewhere in your code? That is, are you using a `ContentResolver` anywhere? Are there certain versions of Android that this only happens in? E.g., it does happen in versions before KitKat, but not newer ones?

Comment: The message literally gets received twice in the recipient's SMS inbox, despite it being sent only once.  And yes - it also appears twice in my SMS app.  So far, it usually appears twice, but it had appeared four times before too.  I am saving my messages in txt files using the app, but I am not using ContentResolver anywhere.  I implemented this app using Ice Cream Sandwich, but it seems to happen with all phones.

Comment: I am getting the impression that the Receiver class in my app is acting too quickly, so that when one SMS message comes in, it senses two or more consecutive ones, and hence records it twice.  Is there any way to delay reading this message if it helps?

Comment: Yeah, that's not really how Receivers work. You simply receiving the message isn't going to affect how many receipts happen. If the SMS app is showing multiple messages, and you're not writing any messages to the Provider, then it really, really sounds like you're just sending multiple messages. Are you doing any kind of auto-reply? That is, are you sure the duplicate messages are coming from the same device, and not just being "echoed" from another? Without seeing more code, all I can suggest atm is to absolutely make sure that you're not somehow sending multiple messages to the same number.

Comment: Hi Mike, yes - I'm absolutely sure that the multiple messages are coming from the same sender, and that no echoes or auto-replies are involved.  I believe I've already included all the relevant code for this problem, so what other code would you like to see?

Comment: Well, it would just be to double-check what you've stated but not included; e.g., to ensure you're not sending multiple times to the same recipient, actually writing messages yourself, etc. The posted code is just the basic send/receive stuff, which isn't really any different than most implementations. Dunno what to tell ya. Every time I've helped someone with multiple message issues, it's always been from accidentally sending multiple times, or saving duplicates. The first thing I'd do is figure out a minimal, consistent dataset where this issue is reproducible, and work from there.

Comment: You should also try including yourself in the recipient list, and see if you can get your device to receive multiple times. It'd be a lot easier to figure out if you can see what's happening first-hand.

Comment: Hi Mike, that's exactly what I've done - sending the messages to myself.  But it was clear that I was receiving twice or more even though I had only sent once.  I am now suspecting that it's because the for loop is executed too quickly - and more quickly than any human being can accomplish, so that it introduces errors whenever I am sending to more than one number.  I'm now trying to introduce a delay between sending each message, but have created another thread for this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521653/delay-for-loop-cycle-in-java

Comment: Yeah, I almost suggested that when we were chatting, but I guess I forgot. FWIW, I've never had a problem with "rapid fire" sending, so I was reluctant to have you change your code like that, only to have it not be the problem. I would point out that if the sending device is showing only one outgoing message per recipient, and the delay turns out to be the fix, then that would be your carrier's fault, really. Anyhoo, I'll have a look at your new post when I get a chance later on, to make sure you get an answer there.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your patience throughout.  I am still very new to app development, so please excuse me if I ask some very silly or obvious questions.  Since you've done 'rapid fire' sending before without any problem, I'm very much inclined to believe that that's not my problem either.  I might try delaying my receiver now, and see if that fixes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this you are making mistake check below code.

```
      if (bundle != null) {
            // get sms objects
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            if (pdus.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            // large message might be broken into many
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                sb.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
            }
            senderNum = messages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
            message = sb.toString();
        }
```

**Update: To check default app**

```
 public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                final String myPackageName = context.getPackageName();
                if (Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context).equals(
                        myPackageName)) {
                    // you are default

                    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                    SmsMessage[] smgs = null;
                    String infoSender = "";
                    String infoSMS = "";

                    if (extras != null) {
                        // Retrieve the sms message received
                        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
                        smgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                        for (int i = 0; i < smgs.length; i++) {
                            smgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                            infoSender += smgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                            infoSMS += smgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // you are not ignore
                }
            } else {
                // for below KitKat do like normal 
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                SmsMessage[] smgs = null;
                String infoSender = "";
                String infoSMS = "";

                if (extras != null) {
                    // Retrieve the sms message received
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
                    smgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                    for (int i = 0; i < smgs.length; i++) {
                        smgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                        infoSender += smgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        infoSMS += smgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, but I'm afraid it still didn't fix the problemm, and multiple messages still get received.  One thing I've noted is that only phones with this app installed are getting multiple messages.  Another thing is that this seems to happen when phone reception is a bit poor.  Hence, a delay in Message 1 arriving will make it arrive twice when reception is good again.  I'm not sure if this is a consistent occurrence, though.  My Android Studio does say that createFromPdu is deprecated - would you be able to advise how to fix that?

Comment: After kitkat only default messaging application can manipulation with db ....so check if your app is default using above snippet if you are not default then dont make notification otherwise ignore. better to show your full receiver?

Comment: I selected Ice Cream Sandwich when I developed this app, so do you mean I need to change it to Kitkat?  Can you please tell me how to check?  For example, where do I type in your code and what should I be observing, etc.?

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience, but I'm afraid still nothing has changed.  My receiver code is about 1300 lines long, but apart from what I've shown here, the rest is just moving text in txt files, so I don't think it'd be wisest to show it here.  I'm getting the impression now that whenever an SMS is received, the receiver in my app gets to work very quickly, but after it receives it once, it still senses the same message coming in, so it receives it again.  Hence, would you possibly know of any method of executing the onReceive method only once when one message comes in?

Comment: put you phone on debug and be vigilant on logcat and check how many apps are creating notification its only your which is creating notification twice our any other app also creating notification.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this modication of your code base will help solve your problem

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] smgs = null;
        String infoSender = "";
        String infoSMS = "";

        if (extras != null) {
             try{
            // Retrieve the sms message received
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
           if(pdus.length==0){return;}
            smgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < smgs.length; i++) {
                smgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                infoSMS += smgs[i].getMessageBody();
            }
               infoSender = smgs[0].getOriginatingAddress();
            }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }
        }
     }
}
```